# Rails/React/Yarn: How can I run "yarn start" from the root of my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, yarnpkg, hivemind

I'm creating a rails application from scratch using the following [blog](https://medium.com/@taylorwu/learning-graphql-with-rails-5f44b1aac0db) which needs me to run `rails s` and then `yarn start` in the `/client` folder of the application (where all the JS and React components will live).

The `/client/package.json` file has some scripts configured to run a server that detects changes in my react components and reloads the components automatically:

**client/package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

I use a program called [hivemind](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/introducing-overmind-and-hivemind) which is a `Procfile` manager and I would like both the rails server process and the yarn process to run together in the same terminal.

I'd like to do something like this in my `Profile`:

```
server: bin/rails server
react:  yarn start
```

The problem is that `Profile` lives in the root of my application and I have to change directory into `client` and then run `yarn start`.

**TL;DR**:

Is there an option with `yarn run` that you can tell it to run from another folder or read a `package.json` file in another folder and have it run the script in that file?

Comment: you can try `cd client && yarn start` in Procfile

Comment: I didn't think of this. That works. If you want to make a post, I'll give you a +1 and if nothing better comes along in the next day or two, I'll give you and rep for correct answer.

Comment: Glad that it helped..! I will make a post so that other people can find the solution easily..!Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write `cmd` arguments in `Procfile`

try changing react command to

```
react: cd client && yarn start
```

It will change the current directory and runs your script

Answer (score 1):

When you run `yarn [command]` `yarn` looks for a file locally called `package.json`. You can add yarn commands inside the `"scripts"` section of this file. In my own rails app root directory I added a `"start"` command that did what Sumanth's answer does but now I can just have

```
react: yarn start
```

in my `Procfile`.

Below is the edited version of my `package.json` file in my app's root path:

```
{
  "name": "create-repack-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm run deploy && echo 'Client Built'",
    "start": "cd client && yarn start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```